# How to execute a SQL Server "select" statement at regular time interval in asp.net c# and display the result in popup

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing an asp.net c# web application. I am facing an issue, there are two users admin and salesman. If the salesman logs in and enter details through one page, the details should be displayed on the admin machine as popup  whenever he should be in any page of that application.

There are several salesmen from several locations, login and enter details and it should be displayed on admin machine.

I hope some should provide a suitable solution for me...

Comment: You can add a timer and enable the time if admin loggs in and check if there are any new records and show the popup

Comment: Gosh, I wouldn't want to be sitting and working at that "admin" machine, with popups all the time ....

Comment: The title is unrelated to the question. You should fix it to reflect what you are asking before the question gets closed. BTW what you *are* asking, is how to push notifications from the server to the browsers and SingalR is ASP.NET's answer to that

Answer (score 1):

Try Signalr for realtime update on both client machines. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Jose,thanks for your solution ,but actually the problem is not to display all details to admin machine and there should be no reply text from admin machine.The popup only contains the transaction number that has entered by the salesman and 2 button one for viewing that particular details and other one for print.The details entered by salesman are stored in a table and if admin close that popup it shouldn't display again

Comment: SignalR is used for duplex communication between client and server(in your case between admin login machine and your application server). It tries to utilise web socket technology when available or fallback to Ajax. In your case a long polling Ajax is also a solution. Poll should check db for new records and display it.